# Windows GUI/Front End Management Tool for Libvirt VMs on a Remote Linux Host

Tags: windows, linux, virtualization

I currently have a few libvirt/QEMU VMs to manage on a headless Ubuntu 18.04 server and would greatly benefit from a GUI management platform that I can run on my Windows 10 workstation. Free would be great if possible.

I did some searching and couldn't find what I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting things to work with MobaXTerm and virt-manager via WSL per this article: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-and-use-virt-manager-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Try cockpit-machines Ubuntu package.

Comment: Your answer has been flag as low quality and might be removed; please have a look at [What is required for an answer to be high quality?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/23377) for some tips on how to improve it.